# Xcode crashes immediately before running on device

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, crash, certificate

(I just noticed this error and fixed it myself. Nonetheless I think it would be helpful to share the fix.)

My Xcode crashed every time when it finished compiling the app and tried to run on a device (iPhone, iPad). Nothing happened on the device. However, Xcode didn't crash the last time I ran the app (about 3 days earlier).

The app ran fine with Simulator though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the reason was that my **developer certificate** has just **expired** yesterday. After re-requesting the certificate and importing it, the app runs again on device. Sadly Xcode didn't issue any error messages about it.